# Chrome windows don't remember size after closing and re-opening

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, gnome3, gnome-shell

Running GNOME 3 (GNOME Shell 3.2.2.1) on Ubuntu 11.10 , I'm seeing a problem with Google Chrome where sometime in the past a pop-under ad has resized my browser window to something like 640x400 , and now every time I open Chrome the window manager displays the browser window at that size.  I can resize the window (either manually or via the WM's Maximize button) but if I close and re-open Chrome the new window is still the tiny, incorrect size.  It doesn't make a difference if I use the WM's Close button, the window's context menu, or exit Chrome via the app's menu itself.  Other apps (gedit) do appear to behave properly.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?  Is it a problem with Chrome, GNOME, or something else?

Comment: Did you install Chrome by compiling or by using a .deb package?

Comment: Try re-installing, it helped me solve the problem, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It is a workaround rather than a cure but there are command line options such as:

> chromium-browser --start-maximized